# find fileName in a folder using apple script

Tags: applescript, directory, filenames

i would like to get the first file name of a folder using appleScript language
it should look like that:

Folder: photo.png, photo1.png, photo2.png, photo3.png

```
tell application "Finder"
   set fileName to (1° file in this case photo.png)
end tell
```

please anyone than can help me out thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost.

```
tell application "Finder"
   set fileName to name of first file of folder "Macintosh HD:path:to:folder"
end tell
```

Comment: i'm supposed not to know the file name :)

Comment: this is actually my code:    tell application "Terminal"
 do script "cd /Applications/android"
 tell application "System Events" to key code 36
 tell application "Finder"
  set fileName to first file of folder "/Users/Damiano/Documents/Apowersoft/Video Download Capture/
  Download/"
  display dialog fileName
  
 end tell
 set fileToDownload to "/Users/Damiano/Documents/Apowersoft/Video Download Capture/Download/" & fileName
 display dialog fileToDownload
 do script "adb push " & fileToDownload & "sdcard/DCIM/Camera/"
end tell

Comment: This is a good example of a misleading question because of pseudo code. Please edit the question and add the real code.

Comment: `set fileName to name of first file of folder "HD:Users:Damiano:Documents:Apowersoft:Video Download Capture:Download"
` doesn't work

Comment: @damianoshushku Are you sure your system partition has name `"HD"`? Not `"Macintosh HD"` as it is by default?

Comment: @Styx yep you were right i've changed the partition name i've forgotten, thx for helping me out it was the partition name was Damiano